# Line Break g elements inside SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

This might be fairly simple question but unable to find the answer. I want to line break `g` element tags inside `svg` element.

CSS

```
.container { position: reletive; width: 200px; background: #ccc; }
.container g { display: inline-block; display: inline; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <svg>
        <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Canada</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(100, 0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Germany</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(200, 0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Norway</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(300, 0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Russia</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(400, 0)">
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">USA</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/furqansafdar/kkux2t60/1/)

Comment: There's no automatic breaking in SVG, you'd have to measure the text using javascript and then do the breaking yourself. Alternatively do it in HTML where there is breaking built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG doesn't have a layout model like HTML, each element is painted on top of the previous elements and doesn't affect positioning of other elements.

You could use separate `<svg />` elements so the HTML layout model can take control of positioning / wrapping the elements:

```css
.container { width: 200px; background: #ccc; }
.container svg { width:100px; margin:0; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg>
        <g>
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Canada</text>
        </g>
    </svg><svg>
        <g>
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Germany</text>
        </g>
    </svg><svg>
        <g>
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Norway</text>
        </g>
    </svg><svg>
        <g>
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">Russia</text>
        </g>
    </svg><svg>
        <g>
            <rect width="18" height="18"></rect>
            <text x="24" y="9" dy=".35em">USA</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 - I liked this approach but why there is big vertical gap even if i specify fixed div height `.container { width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #ccc; }`?

Comment: @FSX 150px is the default height for svg - `svg { height:0px;   /*or the value you need*/ }`